# MongoDB validation doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

first i'd like to thank everybody that is willing to help me.

Here is my problem:

I create a collection with validation schema on my mongoDB.

I try two way for achieve this. First with query operator:

```
db.createCollection("users", {
    validator: {
       $or: [
             { username:      { $regex: /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/ }},
             { firstName:     { $type: "string" }},
             { lastName:      { $type: "string" }},
             { mail:          { $type: "string" }},
             { password:      { $regex: /[A-Z0-9]{128}/ }},
             { salt:          { $regex: /[A-Z0-9]{64}/ }},
             { birthdate:     { $regex: /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/ }},
             { picture:       { $type: "binData" }},
             { activationKey: { $regex: /[A-Z0-9]{64}/ }},
             { activated:     { $type: "bool" }}
         ]
     }
 });
```

NB: I try to change the $or operator by $and too

Second, with $jsonSchema validation:

```
db.createCollection("users", {
    validator: {
        $jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            properties: {
                username:      { pattern: /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/},
                firstName:     { bsonType: "string" },
                lastName:      { bsonType: "string" },
                mail:          { bsonType: "string" },
                password:      { pattern: /[A-Z0-9]{128}/ },
                salt:          { pattern: /[A-Z0-9]{64}/ },
                birthdate:     { pattern: /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/ },
                picture:       { bsonType: "binData" },
                activationKey: { pattern: /[A-Z0-9]{64}/ },
                activated:     { bsonType: "bool" }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**edit: pattern must be a string like this**

```
db.createCollection("users", {
    validator: {
        $jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            properties: {
                username:      { pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$"},
                firstName:     { bsonType: "string" },
                lastName:      { bsonType: "string" },
                mail:          { bsonType: "string" },
                password:      { pattern: "[A-Z0-9]{128}" },
                salt:          { pattern: "[A-Z0-9]{64}" },
                birthdate:     { pattern: "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$" },
                picture:       { bsonType: "binData" },
                activationKey: { pattern: /[A-Z0-9]{64}/ },
                activated:     { bsonType: "bool" }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

But in both case the validation act strangely. I can't insert document with a single field birthdate which doesn't match the regex, like this:

```
> db.users.insert({birthdate: "invalid string"});
Document failed validation
```

But i can insert a document with invalid birthdate as long as there is other field in my insert query.

```
> db.getCollection('users').insert({birthdate: "invalid string", username:"yolo"})
Inserted 1 record(s) in 2ms
```

It confused me so much and i really don't know what i did wrong...

Comment: Make birthdate be required and see if that fixes it.

Comment: First birthdate required make both insert query to work. So i dig deeper and i found out that with $jsonSchema pattern must be a string... So now it works with $jsonSchema but i still don't get why the validation with query operator doesn't work.